How do FIWARE Scorpio temporal entities are stored and work?
I deploy a basic FIWARE Scorpio stack with a docker compose :
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ngb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ngb
      POSTGRES_DB: ngb
    
  scorpio:
    image: scorpiobroker/all-in-one-runner:java-latest
    environment:
      DBHOST: postgres
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

I also have a .sh code to add entities, a part of it is :
SCORPIO_URL="http://localhost:9090/ngsi-ld/v1/temporal/entities"
NGSI_LD_CONTEXT="https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context-v1.7.jsonld"

FIWARE_SERVICE="test_service"
FIWARE_SERVICEPATH="/weather"

create_weather_entity() {
    response=$(curl -X POST "$SCORPIO_URL" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/ld+json" \
        -H "fiware-service: $FIWARE_SERVICE" \
        -H "fiware-servicepath: $FIWARE_SERVICEPATH" \
        -d '{
            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:WeatherObserved:001",
            "type": "WeatherObserved",
            "temperature": {
                "value": 23,
                "unitCode": "CEL",
                "type": "Property",
                "observedAt": "2024-10-10T12:00:00Z"  
            },
            "barometricPressure": {
                "value": 720,
                "unitCode": "hPa",
                "type": "Property",
                "observedAt": "2024-10-10T12:00:00Z"  
            },
            "dateObserved": {
                "value": "2024-10-10T12:00:00Z",
                "type": "Property"
            },
            "source": {
                "value": "http://www.aemet.es",
                "type": "Property"
            },
            "@context": [
                {
                    "WeatherObserved": "urn:mytypes:WeatherObserved",
                    "temperature": "myuniqueuri:temperature",
                    "barometricPressure": "myuniqueuri:barometricPressure",
                    "dateObserved": "myuniqueuri:dateObserved",
                    "source": "myuniqueuri:source"
                },
                "'$NGSI_LD_CONTEXT'"
            ]
        }')
    echo "Create WeatherObserved Response: $response"
}

And a code to simulate the sending of measurements :
SCORPIO_URL="http://localhost:9090/ngsi-ld/v1/temporal/entities/"
NGSI_LD_CONTEXT="https://fiware.github.io/data-models/context.jsonld"

FIWARE_SERVICE="test_service"
FIWARE_SERVICEPATH="/weather"

send_weather_measurements() {
    local temperature=$(shuf -i 15-35 -n 1)
    local pressure=$(shuf -i 700-750 -n 1)
    local timestamp=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ")

    echo "Sending WeatherObserved measurement:"
    echo "  Temperature: ${temperature} °C"
    echo "  Barometric Pressure: ${pressure} hPa"
    echo "  Observed At: ${timestamp}"

    curl -X PATCH "${SCORPIO_URL}urn:ngsi-ld:WeatherObserved:001/attrs" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/ld+json" \
        -H "fiware-service: $FIWARE_SERVICE" \
        -H "fiware-servicepath: $FIWARE_SERVICEPATH" \
        -d '{
            "temperature": {
                "type": "Property",
                "value": '"$temperature"',
                "observedAt": "'"$timestamp"'"
            },
            "barometricPressure": {
                "type": "Property",
                "value": '"$pressure"',
                "observedAt": "'"$timestamp"'"
            },
            "dateObserved": {
                "type": "Property",
                "value": "'"$timestamp"'"
            },
            "@context": "'$NGSI_LD_CONTEXT'"
        }'
}

I would like to store these historical contexts into the postgres sql db (not ok), and then connect it to Grafana (this part should be ok).
When I do :
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9090/ngsi-ld/v1/temporal/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:WeatherObserved:001" 
-H "Content-Type: application/ld+json" 
-H "fiware-service: test_service" 
-H "fiware-servicepath: /weather"
It works so the entity is saved. But when I check inside the postgres db, I only see these tables and can't find the ones corresponding to my entities :
 tiger    | faces                      | table | ngb
 tiger    | featnames                  | table | ngb
 tiger    | geocode_settings           | table | ngb
 tiger    | geocode_settings_default   | table | ngb
 tiger    | loader_lookuptables        | table | ngb
 tiger    | loader_platform            | table | ngb
 tiger    | loader_variables           | table | ngb
 tiger    | pagc_gaz                   | table | ngb
 tiger    | pagc_lex                   | table | ngb
 tiger    | pagc_rules                 | table | ngb
 tiger    | place                      | table | ngb
 tiger    | place_lookup               | table | ngb
 tiger    | secondary_unit_lookup      | table | ngb
 tiger    | state                      | table | ngb
 tiger    | state_lookup               | table | ngb
 tiger    | street_type_lookup         | table | ngb
 tiger    | tabblock                   | table | ngb
 tiger    | tabblock20                 | table | ngb
 tiger    | tract                      | table | ngb
 tiger    | zcta5                      | table | ngb
 tiger    | zip_lookup                 | table | ngb
 tiger    | zip_lookup_all             | table | ngb
 tiger    | zip_lookup_base            | table | ngb
 tiger    | zip_state                  | table | ngb
 tiger    | zip_state_loc              | table | ngb
 topology | layer                      | table | ngb
 topology | topology                   | table | ngb

How should I do to store the historical values into a postgres SQL database?
Thank you in advance for any help!
